# Suggestions for compression library to get byte[] as small as possible without considering cpu expense?

Tags: java, compression

Correct me if I'm approaching this wrong, but I have a queue server and a bunch of java workers that I'm running on in a cluster. My queue has work units that are very small but there are many of them. So far my benchmarks and review of the workers has shown that I get about 200mb/second.

So I'm trying to figure out how to get more work units via my bandwidth.  Currently my CPU usage is not very high(40-50%) because it can process the data faster than the network can send it. I want to get more work through the queue and am willing to pay for it via expensive compression/decompression(since half of each core is idle right now).

I have tried java LZO and gzip, but was wondering if there was anything better(even if its more cpu expensive)?

Updated: data is a byte[]. Basically the queue only takes it in that format so I am using `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write two ints and a int[] to to a byte[] format. The values in int[] are all ints between 0 to 100(or 1000 but the vast majority of the numbers are zeros). The lists are quite large anywhere from 1000 to 10,000 items(again, majority zeros..never more than 100 non-zero numbers in the int[])

Comment: What sort of data is it? Text?

Comment: @dbaupp good question, sorry about not mentioning that. I updated the question to include it.

Comment: Are you saying you saw improvement when you tried gzip but even at its most cpu intensive setting you have excess cpu time?

Comment: @learningJava, what sort of values do the `int[]`s take? (I'm asking these question because the structure of the data will change what is the best compression method)

Comment: @joshp I'm not sure how to tweak gzip's setting I just streamed it into `GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(data);` and it made a impact but I'm trying to see if I can get the greater impact(yes the 40% cpu is based on gzip/lzo)

Comment: @dbaupp the values in int[] are all ints between 0 to 100(or 1000 but the vast majority of the numbers are zeros). The lists are quite large anywhere from 1000 to 10,000 items(again, majority zeros..never more than 100 non-zero numbers in the int[])

Comment: I would expect standard compression techniques to be very good at that sort of data...although if there are at most 100 non-zero numbers, then why not just send an array of the indices of the nonzero numbers and their values?  That'll only be 200 ints, tops...

Comment: @LouisWasserman The order of the items in the list is important(the zeros mean that certain data is not active but its still accounted for).

Comment: @learningJava I have not used gzip from java. It typically has 9 levels, and the highest usually cross the line of insufficient reward for the cpu time, for my use. Can you get the GZIP or Deflate output stream constructor to let you specify a level? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Okay, so the order of the items in the list is important.  That's why you send the _indices_ of the nonzero numbers, as well as their values.  That's enough information to reconstitute the same array _exactly_, and it's still at least 5x cheaper than sending the array itself, from what you've told us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like using a custom compression mechanism that exploits the structure of the data could be very efficient.

Firstly, using a `short[]` (16 bit data type) instead of an `int[]` will halve (!) the amount of data sent, you can do this because the numbers are easily between `-2^15` (-32768) and `2^15-1` (32767). This is ridiculously easy to implement.

Secondly, you could use a scheme similar to run-length encoding: a positive number represents that number literally, while a negative number represents that many zeros (after taking absolute values). e.g.

```
[10, 40, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0] <=> [10, 40, -3, 30, -1, 100, -4]
```

This is harder to implement that just substituting `short` for `int`, but will provide ~80% compression in the very worst case (1000 numbers, 100 non-zero, none of which are consecutive).

I just did some simulations to work out the compression ratios. I tested the method I described above, and the one suggested by Louis Wasserman and sbridges. Both performed very well.

Assuming the length of the array and the number of non-zero numbers are both uniformly between their bounds, both methods save about 5400 `int`s (or `short`s) on average with a compressed size of about 2.5% the original! The run-length encoding method seems to save about 1 additional `int` (or average compressed size that is 0.03% smaller), i.e. basically no difference, so you should use the one that is easiest to implement. The following are histograms of the compression ratios for 50000 random samples (they are very similar!).

[image: histograms]

**Summary**: using `short`s instead of `int`s and one of the compression methods, you will be able to compress the data to about 1% of its original size!

For the simulation, I used the following R script:

```
SIZE <- 50000

lengths <- sample(1000:10000, SIZE, replace=T)
nonzeros <- sample(1:100, SIZE, replace=T)

f.rle <- function(len, nonzero) {
  indexes <- sort(c(0,sample(1:len, nonzero, F)))
  steps <- diff(indexes)
  sum(steps > 1) + nonzero # one short per run of zeros, and one per zero
}

f.index <- function(len, nonzero) {
  nonzero * 2
}

# using the [value, -1 * number of zeros,...] method
rle.comprs <- mapply(f.rle, lengths, nonzeros)
print(mean(lengths - rle.comprs)) # average number of shorts saved

rle.ratios <- rle.comprs / lengths * 100
print(mean(rle.ratios)) # average compression ratio

# using the [(index, value),...] method
index.comprs <- mapply(f.index, lengths, nonzeros)
print(mean(lengths - index.comprs)) # average number of shorts saved

index.ratios <- index.comprs / lengths * 100
print(mean(index.ratios)) # average compression ratio


par(mfrow=c(2,1))
hist(rle.ratios, breaks=100, freq=F, xlab="Compression ratio (%)", main="Run length encoding")
hist(index.ratios, breaks=100, freq=F, xlab="Compression ratio (%)", main="Store indices")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding your data as two [varints](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), the first varint is the index of the number in the sequence, the second is the number itself.  For entries which are 0, write nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an implementation of an RLE algorithm.  This operates on a byte array, so could be used as an in-line filter with your existing code.  It should safely handle large or negative values should your data change in the future.

It encodes a sequence of zeros as {0}{qty} where {qty} is in the range 1..255.  All other bytes are stored as the byte itself.  You squish your byte array before sending, and bloat it back to full size when receiving.

```
public static byte[] squish(byte[] bloated) {
    int size = bloated.length;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 * size);
    bb.putInt(size);
    int zeros = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (bloated[i] == 0) {
            if (++zeros == 255) {
                bb.putShort((short) zeros);
                zeros = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (zeros > 0) {
                bb.putShort((short) zeros);
                zeros = 0;
            }
            bb.put(bloated[i]);
        }
    }
    if (zeros > 0) {
        bb.putShort((short) zeros);
        zeros = 0;
    }
    size = bb.position();
    byte[] buf = new byte[size];
    bb.rewind();
    bb.get(buf, 0, size).array();
    return buf;
}

public static byte[] bloat(byte[] squished) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(squished);
    byte[] bloated = new byte[bb.getInt()];
    int pos = 0;
    while (bb.position() < bb.capacity()) {
        byte value = bb.get();
        if (value == 0) {
            bb.position(bb.position() - 1);
            pos += bb.getShort();
        } else {
            bloated[pos++] = value;
        }
    }
    return bloated;
}
```

Comment: It appears at a glance that this could throw a BufferOverflowException if the 'squished' size ends up being larger than the 'bloated' size during compression.  Still +1, this is a very clear RLE example, but could use some docs.

Comment: Good catch.  Any single 0x00 would expand to two bytes.  I doubled the buffer size to accommodate the worst-case.

Answer (score 1):

I've been impressed with BZIP2, compared with 7z and gzip.  I haven't personally tried this Java implementation, but it looks like it would be easy to substitute your GZIP call for this one and verify the results.

http://www.kohsuke.org/bzip2

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try all the major ones on your data stream and see which works best. You should also consider that some algorithms will take longer to run, adding more latency to the queue. This may or may not be a problem depending on your application.

You can sometimes get better compression if you know something about the data. (dbaupp's answer covers this approach nicely)

This [comparison of compression algorithms](http://blog.terzza.com/linux-compression-comparison-gzip-vs-bzip2-vs-lzma-vs-zip-vs-compress/) might be useful. From the article:

[image: compression ratio of popular compression algorithms]